# Duplicated Fingerprint (Google API Manager OAuth 2.0 ClientID for Android) even after delete

Tags: android, google-signin

We have developed an Android app for our client and have recently added Google Signin to the app. Following the Google Signin's setup wizard (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating), it automatically generates OAuth 2.0 ClientID for Android in our API console for this project. When we entered this app's SHA1 fingerprint, it warned that there is already a duplicate entry in the system. We found that our client had added the fingerprint in their API console already, so we asked them to delete it in their account. Even after one and half weeks, the system still warned of "Duplicate fingerprint".

Is there any extra steps that we have missed to release the use of this SHA1 fingerprint from our client's API account, so that we can add it in our configuration settings?